# Changing Sinc function to regular sin in mathematica

Tags: python, output, wolfram-mathematica, trigonometry, pyomo

I have a mathematica function which output is a sum of Sinc https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html functions. I need to send said output to a coworker who uses Pyomo https://www.pyomo.org/ for optimization. We have discovered that said optimization software doesn't understand Sinc even if regular Python does. I need to know if there is a way to change the output so instead of using Sinc it returns Sin(x)/x.

I have looked for a solution in Mathworks, but the function seems very limited. I have also checked question like https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/simplify-sinx-x-to-sincx/19856 or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144899/simplify-is-excluding-indeterminate-expression-from-output.

However, I haven't found a way to solve the issue.

I have attempted to define by hand sinc as six(x)/x, but this doesn't work due to the indetermination at 0

This is how I define sinc:

```
sinc = Sinc[Pi #] & ;
sincB = (Sin[Pi #]/(Pi #)) & ;
```

This is where I use the data to construct an analytic expression. The upper one is the one I used in the past and the lower one is the one that I have constructed now.

```
shannonIP[v_, w_] = 
 Total[#3* sinc[(v - #1)/dDelta]*sinc[(w - #2)/dDelta] & @@@ 
   interpolatedData]
shannonIPB[v_, w_] = 
 Total[#3* sincB[(v - #1)/dDelta]*sincB[(w - #2)/dDelta] & @@@ 
   interpolatedData]
```

The resulting expression of the upper code returns a sum of Sincs, the resulting expression of the lower code returns a sum of sin(x)/x, but if evaluated at some points I run in the error of 1/0.

Is there a way to "fix" the output of the lower code or to transform the output of the upper one to an expression readable by Pyomo?

[image] This figure is the function constructed using Sinc.

[image] This figure is the function constructed using Sin[x]/(x+0.0000000000000001)

Answer (score 1):

for arguments near zero, you should compute sinc(x) as 1-(x^2)/6+(x^4)/120

Comment: I have finally constructed it as sincC = Piecewise[{{(Sin[Pi* #]/(Pi*(#))), # >= 
       0.00000000000000000000000001}, {1 - (#^2)/6 + (#^4)/
        120 - (#^6)/5040, # < 0.00000000000000000000000001}}] & ; However, the results aren't good. The function looks like the last one frmon the question